# GameObject.SetActiveRecursively (true) obsolete?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to use:

```
GameObject.Find("teleportation").SetActiveRecursively(true);
```

`GameObject.SetActiveRecursively(bool)` is obsolete, it say to use `GameObject.SetActive()` instead which is now inherited by children.

In my hierachy I have an object active and his child inactive.
If I use `GameObject.SetActive()` on the active object, the child is NOT activated.
If I use `GameObject.SetActiveRecursively()` on the active object, the child is activated.

So, should I use something different to make active a child?
I don't understand why `GameObject.SetActive()` won't work.

Comment: I don't see in the documentation where it says "GameObject.SetActive() ... is now inherited by children."  Can you explain what you mean by that statement?

Comment: A quick google search suggests this function has been obsolete for [some time](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/353475/setactiverecursively-is-now-obsolete-in-unity-40.html) now - according to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) it doesn't exist in the newest version at all

Comment: @Amy You can see it trough code, the line is underlined with greens waves. thats mean its depreciated.

Comment: I understand what deprecated and obsoleted mean.  That wasn't what I asked.  What does the "is now inherited by children" statement mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SetActiveRecursively` function is obsolete like you mentioned.  You should now be using `SetActive()`.

You can use recursion and `SetActive()` to replicate the function of `SetActiveRecursively`. You can also put it in an extension method.

```
public static class ExtentionMethod
{
    public static void SetActiveRecursivelyExt(this GameObject obj, bool state)
    {
        obj.SetActive(state);
        foreach (Transform child in obj.transform)
        {
            SetActiveRecursivelyExt(child.gameObject, state);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("teleportation");
obj.SetActiveRecursivelyExt(true);
```

Comment: So a function that already existed and conveniently took care of the job has been deprecated without offering a replacement..!? Why would that be?

Comment: @ThomasHilbert That's Unity for you.The replacement is  `GameObject.SetActive()` but its behavior is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

This was 5 years ago but for others who look for solution simpler than the one given before, I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
gameObjectTarget.transform.GetChild(childNum).SetActive(true);
```

- gameObjectTarget is the gameObject parent you want.
- childNum is the child number in hierarchy starting from 0 for the first child of the gameObject your using.

Hope it helps :)